# Spring Boot: Re-use code in another project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am building a project (Parrent) that use mysql data. Instead of writing new code for that, I want to re-use code in another project (SQLConnection) that I have finished before.

Normally, I will import SQLConnection to Parrent:

```
Java Build Path => Project => Add
```

But when I do that and call function from SQLConnection, it shows error

```
Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
```

I know someone who achieved the same by using the `Maven build`, but I have no idea how to do it with `Maven`.

If someone have ever faced this situation, please leave me a comment.

Thank you!

Comment: Use maven, you really can't do Spring Dev work without it. Better yet, use Spring boot, create your project in Spring Initializr too. Tip 2, try not to litter SO with these types of questions.

Comment: Litter? What do you mean ?. I post the question cuz I have no idea and experience. what you know doesn't mean I know.

Comment: Use https://start.spring.io/. Use maven, look at a tutorial. Reframe from asking questions here till you do your own ground work. Maven is not a 'work around' most projects developed in Spring use it. Just do some tutorials don't just ask questions here will get you no where.

Comment: Or, alternatively, Gradle, but they're comparable tools that do the same jobs. Use one.

Comment: First what kind of code have you written to access MySQL? In Spring boot you can derive from `CrudRepository` for example and offer a dependency to the database driver and that's it..?So I don't see here a real chance to reuse code? (For example: http://www.javainterviewpoint.com/spring-boot-crudrepository-example/)...

Answer (score 0):

I hope u already have a piece of java code that access MySQL data in SQLconnection project . Create a jar of SQLconnection , use it as maven dependency (Pom.xml)in your Parrent project. Once dependency is injected , import the java class of SQLconnection in Parrent class for access purpose .

Basically I’m asking make SQLconnection as a library for Parrent project .